# not returning anything although there is no problem public static int

Tags: java

I got homework to do where I need to make it return 1 if sum is bigger or equals to 2 and 0 otherwise. But it's not returning anything.

Thanks for help.
Here is the program:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Singer s1 = new Singer("yoav",40,8);
    Singer [] sArr = new Singer[9];
    String[] nameArr = new String[] {
        "Ariel", "Dana", "Eyal", "Miri", "Keren"
    };
    System.out.println(s1);
    for(int i = 0; i < sArr.length; i++) {
        int name = (int)(Math.random() * nameArr.length);
        int age = (int)(Math.random() * 20);
        int album = (int)(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
        sArr[i] = new Singer(nameArr[name], s1.getAge() -age, s1.getGoldA() - album);
        System.out.println(sArr[i]);
    }   
}

public static int twoOrLess(Singer [] s1Arr) {
    int sum = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < s1Arr.length - 1; i++) {
        if(s1Arr[i].getGoldA() < s1Arr[i+1].getGoldA()) {
            sum = sum + 1;
        }
    }
    if(sum >= 2) {
        return 1;
    }
    else {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the "it" that you claim is never returning anything?  You've got this `twoOrLess` method that you never actually call, which may be your problem.

Comment: What do you mean by "its not returning anything"? Where are you calling `twoOrLess`? So far, you're not using it anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You never called `twoOrLess`, so you just call it from your `main`.

`twoOrLess` does not get called automatically like `main`. You have to call `twoOrLess`.

**EDIT**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ...
    int value = twoOrLess(); // put an array of some objects of Singer
    System.out.println(value);
}
```

Comment: ok, so what should i do?

Comment: and by it i made a program that contains list of ten singers an their golden album count, and i need to make the program return 1 if i have in the list two or more singers that the singer in place [i] will have less albums than the singer in place [i+1]

Comment: You have to call it `twoOrLess` in `main` as the answer says. Do you know how to call a method?

Comment: but the mission is to make it outside of the main.
as i did in the public static int twoOrLess

Comment: twoOrLess does not get called automatically like `main`, so you have to call it.

Comment: so how i do that?

Comment: Just updated the code.